# Testing ASP.NET sites using master pages with Selenium

Tags: asp.net, html, selenium

What is a good approach to avoiding Selenium tests being broken when dealing with the changing "Name" and "Id" attributes of a control that is rendered on a ASP.NET page using a master page?  I want to avoid changing my tests when ASP.NET renders the web page's controls with different DOM identifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/AutomatedTestingOfASPNETWebApplicationsUsingSelenium.aspx

> Selenium
>   solves this problem using XPATH and
>   providing the ability to locate
>   controls based on XPATH expressions,
>   alleviating the need to hard code HTML
>   tag structure into a test script. For
>   example, the ASP.NET runtime may
>   render ID attributes that look like:

```
id="ctl00_cphContents_gridMaint_DataGrid"
```

> Finding this control using an XPATH
>   expression can be simplified to
>   something like this:

```
table[contains(@id, "gridMaint")]
```

> In the event the nesting of the
>   DataGrid changes the script will
>   continue to function properly as long
>   as table's ID contains the text
>   "gridMaint".

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  I'm curious about where I would make this modification to my test at.  Is this done through the html source view of the Selenium test, or done through the API provided?  Also can I use this technique with the API as I modify tests I code using .NET?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use CSS locators. They're normally less fragile than XPath. For example, to target a div with a class of .myDiv you can use the locator "css=.myDiv". If the specified element has other classes the CSS locator will still work, although the XPath equivalent would change from "//div[@class='myDiv']" to "//div[contains(@class, 'myDiv']". Also, CSS locators tend to be faster than XPath across browsers.